# Find exact value

Tags: plotting, numerics

I want to know exact x'[t] value where z[t]=0

I know approximate x'[t] value is 107

but I cannot find how to find exact x'[t] value

```
    (*1 mph = 0.44704 m/s
    50000ft=15240m*)

    g = 9.81;
    {d, Subscript[c, 1], Subscript[c, 2]} = {0.2 2, 1.55 10^-4 d, 0.22 d^2};
    mass = 100;

    ls0 = NDSolve[{x''[t] + Subscript[c, 2]/mass ((x'[t] + 26.8)^2 + z'[t]^2)^(1/2) (x'[t] + 26.8) == 0, z''[t] + Subscript[c, 2]/mass ((x'[t] + 26.8)^2 + z'[t]^2)^(1/2) z'[t] + g == 0, z[0] == 15240, z'[0] == 0, x'[0] == 107, x[0] == 0}, {x, z}, {t, 0, 1000}]

ParametricPlot[
Evaluate[{x[t], z[t]} /. ls0], {t, 0, 110}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {speed, flying altitude}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're using a numerical method.... What do you mean by "exact"?

Comment: I know What you mean.. But I don't know how to code numerically What I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t0 = t /. First@N@Solve[{Evaluate[z[t] /. ls0] == 0}, t]
```

> 104.606

```
z[t0] /. ls0
```

> {-7.25357*10^-13}

```
x'[t0] /. ls0
```

> {-26.3732}